# how to make every variable in list unnested? python

Tags: list

```
import itertools
def unnest_list(listone,listtwo):
 last=[listone[x] for x in range(len(listone)) if x%2==1]
 last.append([listtwo[x] for x in range(len(listtwo)) if x%2==0])
 return list(itertools.chain(*last))
print(something([3, 6, 9, 12, 15, 18, 21], [4, 8, 12, 16, 20, 24, 28]))
```

trying to make the list unnested, at the end of the func,
last=[6, 12, 18, [4, 12, 20, 28]], after using itertools,chain(*last) it gives an error: "TypeError: 'int' object is not iterable"

Comment: your question is too imprecise. You should use keywords to indicate the programming language (looks like Python), and make an effort to state your problem more clearly, for example write what the output is that you are expecting and what the output is you are getting, or the precise error message. Also: a functionname "something" isn't very informative.

Comment: tried to make it more clear.

Comment: Still not clear what you want to achieve. "Unnesting" means flattening, for example convert [[1,2], [3,4]] to [1, 2, 3, 4] (normally the term unnesting is used for dics and not for lists). You pass two "unnested" lists to your function, so what is there to unnest?

Comment: the last value of last is [6, 12, 18, [4, 12, 20, 28]] i need to unnest it, how do i do that?